# Apollo state variables in useQuery

Tags: reactjs, graphql

In my react app I have a useQuery hook that has variables based on state. Like so,

```
const [criteria, setCriteria] = useState('');
const [sortBy, setSortBy] = useState([]);

const { data, loading, error, refetch, fetchMore } = useQuery(SEARCH_PROFILE, {
    variables: {
      criteria,
      sortBy,
      limit: 10,
    },
    fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
});
```

The problem is that in the chrome networks tab it calls SEARCH_PROFILE 4 or 5 times on load. I think it is because of the state variables in the query. What is an alternative way of doing this without calling the database so many times?

Comment: no, it is not normal ... not the reason of multiple requests ... this component [for some reason] rerendered (I'd say even replaced with new one) in parent?

Comment: How can I check that? I have another useLazyQuery hook too... and also when I remove the sortBy from variables it gets called -2 times

Comment: hmm, IDK ... w/o `fetchPolicy`? ... some of https://github.com/trojanowski/react-apollo-hooks/issues/36 ?